# when datepicker class is used in input field, bootstrap datepicker (autoclose,endDate,startDate) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

the following code is not working if I add datepicker in the input field class

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#ActionDateInput").datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    endDate: new Date()
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="ActionDateInput" class="datepicker form-control" placeholder="Date" name="date" autocomplete="off"/>
```

But if I remove datepicker from the class, it works.
HTML

```
<input type="text" id="ActionDateInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" name="date" autocomplete="off"/>
```

I want to keep the datepicker in the class for design purpose.  I used bootstrap-datepicker

```
<script src="${contextPath}/resources/asset/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```

Comment: Could you try renaming your `datepicker` class and see if the problem persists?

Comment: No, then it works fine. But the date format changes. So for that reason I have to keep the datepicker  in the class

Comment: $("#ActionDateInput").datepicker().datepicker("setEndDate",new Date());  this is working though datepicker is still used

Comment: The `datepicker` class has nothing to do with the _datepicker_ keyword mentioned in the following piece of code `$("#ActionDateInput").datepicker().datepicker("setEndDate",new Date());`. The `datepicker()` is a _function_ and has nothing to do with the _class_ `datepicker` which you have inserted.

Comment: Is it possible that you can provide a js fiddle?

Comment: Renaming datepicker class or removing it completely working fine as usual, but I am intrigued to know why it is not working if I keep the datepicker class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
 $("#ActionDateInput").datepicker().datepicker("setEndDate",new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

The `datepicker` class is used by the *bootstrap-datepicker* plugin. If you download the plugin's sources, in the *bootstrap-datepicker.css* file you can see that there is styling applied to the mentioned class and on some children elements of it. That is why everything works fine when you either not use it or when you rename it.

**Thus, I would strongly recommend you NOT to use the `datepicker` class since it is used
by the plugin internally.**